# How do I display the woocommerce email product attribute terms or value?

Tags: php, email, woocommerce

I want to display the product attribute in my woocommerce email such as invoice email.
This is displaying the product attribute in woocommerce email 
It display like -> size : s
But I want to remove the text "size:"

```
   <td><?php echo $item_meta->display( true, true ); ?></td>
```

This is displaying the product attribute in woocommerce email 
It display like -> m , s
This is what I want but it display all the size. It doesn't display the size that the customers pick.
For example, it should display like -> s , if the customer choose the size "s"
And if the customer choose the size "m", it should just display "m"

```
   <td><?php echo $_product->get_attribute( 'size' ) ?></td>
```

The first code I provide, doesn't tell which product attribute I want to display. How about if I have 2 attribute, for example, size and color. And it will show all attributes? I don't want that.
The second code I provide, it does say the product attribute "size" but it shows all the "size" value.
Anyone know how to display it the way I want ?